# How to set current time to a Date object

Tags: typescript

I have a date input and I keep selected date in a `Date` object. It's output is like `2021-03-16 00:00:00`. I want to set this date object's time part to current time.

My desired output is like this: `2021-03-16 15:56:00`. How can I achieve that?

Comment: Please add some examples of your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done much nicer with some other JS libraries (see [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/)) but for vanilla js this works fine.

```js
const inputDate = new Date("2021-03-16 00:00:00");
const currentDate = new Date();

const out = new Date(
  inputDate.setHours(
    currentDate.getHours(),
    currentDate.getMinutes(),
    currentDate.getSeconds()
  )
);
console.log(out);
```

EDIT: Now using `Date.setHours(hrs, min, sec)` as per the comment by user [VLAZ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3689450/vlaz).

Comment: This will do the job. Thanks.

Comment: No real need to do the arithmetic yourself: `inputDate.setHours(currentDate.getHours(), currentDate.getMinutes(), currentDate.getSeconds())`. If you want to clone the date before that, just `new Date(inputDate)` is enough.